# How to get a query parameter in koa

Tags: node.js, typescript, query-string, koa, tsc

I am using koa.js with typescript. It will give me an error, which was describe in the below screenshot. I have also checked the typed version of koa it will definition for a query is a **ParsedUrlQuery**

```
const email: string = ctx.request.query.email;
```

[image]

Comment: Don't share screenshots. Edit your question and add the code/errors there.

Answer (score 1):

As the error states, you are trying to set something of type 'string | string[] | undefined' to something you have defined to only be a string. Remove the 'string' type declaration on the email constant

```
const email = ctx.request.query.email;
```

With the amount of information you have given, I can not help solve the question you have stated in the title. However, this will solve that error message you are getting.